# create a falling object and click on it in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to developing Android apps. I want to make some rectangle objects randomly falling from top to bottom, and users are able to click on these objects. How do I create these rectangles and make them falling randomly and clickable. (Should I create the rectangles as buttons in .xml? How can I make them move if they are buttons. Or do I create the rectangles in a Java class? If so, how do I make them clickable). 
What classes and libraries can I look into to do this small project?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using animation class you can animate any object, whether its a button or anything else.

if i wanted to achieve such a thing, i will use Canvas.

There is also a library on [Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/) which do exactly what you want, i searched but i couldn't find it for you.